# Applying css or manipulating and DOM elements of office js dialoque

Tags: office-js, office-fabric

I want to increase the `height` of `div` inside the `div` with `class=ms-Dialog-content content_49e4f91a` which is present inside the `iframe` .

Is there any way to apply css inside an office.js dialog?

Please suggest.Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for selecting the first element within another element by class, would be `document.getElementsByClassName({class-name}).firstChild`.

I'm not clear on the scenario you're trying to execute here but I am a bit concerned based on the screenshot. I can see an `iframe` under the `div` you're asking about. If you're attempting to set the height of a dialog created using the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins), this should be specified when you call [displayDialogAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync).